# Predefined Windows icons: Unicode

Tags: winapi

I am assigning to the `lpszIcon` member of the `MSGBOXPARAMSW` structure(notice the `W`). I want to use one of the predefined icons like `IDI_APPLICATION` or `IDI_WARNING` but they are all ASCII (defined as `MAKEINTRESOURCE`). I tried doing this:

```
MSGBOXPARAMSW mbp = { 0 };
mbp.lpszIcon = (LPCWSTR) IDI_ERROR;
```

but then no icon displayed at all. So how can I use the unicode versions of the `IDI_` icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ANSI or Unicode variant of a numeric resource ID. The code that you use to set `lpszIcon` is correct. It is idiomatic to use the [`MAKEINTRESOURCE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648029.aspx) macro rather than a cast, but the cast has identical meaning. Your problem lies in the other code, the code that we cannot see.

Reading between the lines, I think that you are targeting ANSI or MBCS. You tried to use `MAKEINTRESOURCE` but that expands to `MAKEINTRESOURCEA`. That's what led you to cast. You should have used `MAKEINTRESOURCEW` to match `MSGBOXPARAMSW`. That would have resolved the compilation error you encountered. You could equally have changed the project to target UNICODE.

But none of that explains why the icon does not appear in the dialog. There has to be a problem elsewhere. If the dialog appears then the most likely explanation is that you have set `hInstance` to a value other than `NULL`. But the code to set `lpszIcon` is correct, albeit not idiomatic.